# How to understand JSR-133 Happens-Before is too Weak Figure6/7

Tags: java, java-memory-model

In the [JSR-133](http://www.cs.umd.edu/~pugh/java/memoryModel/jsr133.pdf), there are two example that state presumably correctly synchronized programs.

The first example is given by figure 6 where:

```
x == y == 0
```

Then, thread 1 modifies the state by:

```
r1 = x; 
if (r1 != 0) 
y = 1;
```

and thread 2 modifies the state by:

```
r2 = y;
if (r2 != 0)
x = 1;
```

The author states that this program is correctly synchronized，However, there is an execution of this program that results in `r1 == r2 == 1`. How would this latter value even be possible?

Furthermore, figure 7 states as an initial state:

```
x == y == 0
```

With thread 1 modifying:

```
r1 = x; 
y = r1;
```

and thread 2 executing:

```
r2 = y;
x = r2;
```

How could this result in `r1 == r2 == 42`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Figure 6** is an example for the JMM's *out of thing air* restriction. Because no field is marked as `volatile`, the JVM is normally allowed to apply optimizations to the example code. This might result in surpising outcomes.

Assume that *thread 1* observed `x = 1` to be true. Do not worry for now, how this could be the case. In this case, it the thread would set `y = 1`. The latter observation would then justify the initial observation of `x = 1` what is however cyclic reasoning. If this was true, `x = y = 1` would be a legal outcome and the JVM could simply replace the code in both threads to write each value. This form of reasoning is forbidden by the JMM such that `x = y = 0` is the only legal result according to the JMM.

A similar argument is made in **figure 7**. Again, assume the observation `x = 42` by *thread 1*. In this case, the thread would write `y = 42`. Based on this observation, one can now argue that the previous `x = 42` is a legal observation. The initial assumption was however made *out of thin air* what is forbidden such that `x = y = 0` is the only legal outcome.

The definition of a *happens-before* relationship only applies to explicitly synchronized programs and would not forbid the hypothetical cyclic reasoning. Therefore, the *out of thin air* restriction is needed. This is of course rather academic but with the JMM being an academic model, it is still necessary to define this limitation.

Because of this, there are no racing conditions in either figure for which value `x` or `y` can take, i.e. there is no racing condition and `x = y = 0` is the only possible observation. It follows that both examples are correctly synchronized despite the absense of `volatile`.

Comment: I am confusing. in Figure6, if (r1 != 0) and if (r2 != 0) will cause y = 1 and x = 1 don't execute, so I think x != 1 and y !=1.Also not have a happens-before consistent execution.

Comment: The argumentation is circular, that is why I wrote that you should first assume a given value. In this case, you can argue for observing the other value which then justifies your previous assumption. The logical model of the JMM addresses such reasoning by *out of thin air values*. Without this restriction such argumentation would be allowed which is why it is addressed explicitly.

Comment: The example code in Figure 7 is not correctly synchronized, as indicated in JSR-133.

Comment: Yes, both examples are. Yet, the out-of-thin air restriction requires the described outcome.

Comment: thx.out-of-thin-air is disallowed by JMM,but is allowed by happen-before memory model.I will continue to read Jeremy Manson's JMM article.

Comment: So, the number 42 is just an example? it could be 23, 80, and any number that unequal to 0?

Comment: As an example value, yes. 42 is the numeric foo as a hitchhikers guide to the galaxy reference. That's why its probably chosen.

Answer (score 0):

#### Figure 6

The happens-before model only works based on *synchronizes-with* and *happens-before* edges. The JLS gives an example of a *happens-before* consistent execution:

```
r1 = x;  // sees write of x = 1
y = 1;
r2 = y;  // sees write of y = 1
x = 1;
```

In this example, the values appear "out of thin air": it is *happens-before* consistent but breaks the causality requirement (there is no sequentially consistent execution that can produce this outcome). Such an execution is therefore not a legal execution.

#### Figure 7

`r1 === r2 == 42` is ***not*** a valid outcome.

There is no synchronization but the only valid outcome is for all the values to be 0 since no other value is assigned to the variables. For example, in `y = r1`, either `r1` has its default value (0) or has the value of `x` (0) - in both cases `y` will be 0.

---

As a side note, you should probably read [Chapter 17 of the JLS](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se8/html/jls-17.html) rather than the original JSR.

Comment: Thanks, JLS is detail.An example of a happens-before consistent execution explains happens-before is not sufficent.

Comment: `r1 == r2 == 42` *is* happens-before consistent. You can find an explanation in the [paper; section 2.2](http://rsim.cs.illinois.edu/Pubs/popl05.pdf).

Answer (score 0):

**Figure 7:** (Figure 6 has been clearly explained by other answers.)

You can find an explanation of `r1 == r2 == 42` for the example code in Figure 7 in the paper ["The Java Memory Model @ POPL'05"](http://rsim.cs.illinois.edu/Pubs/popl05.pdf). The following is from Section 2.2:

Figure 2 (in the paper) contains a common example of a program for which careful semantics are required. It is incorrectly synchronized; all sequentially consistent executions of this program exhibit data races between Threads `1` and `2`. However, we need to provide a strong guarantee for this code: we need
to ensure that a value such as `42` will not appear out of thin air in `r1` and `r2`.

There are no current optimizations that would permit such an *out-of-thin-air* result. However, in a future aggressive system, `Thread 1` could speculatively write the value `42` to `y`, which would allow `Thread 2` to read `42` for `y` and write it out to `x`, which would allow `Thread 1` to read `42` for `x`, and justify its original speculative write of `42` for `y`.

A self-justifying write speculation like that one can create serious security violations and needs to be disallowed. For example, this would be a serious problem if the value that was produced out of thin air was a reference to an object that the thread was not supposed to have (because of, for example, security guarantees).

Comment: I read section 2.2 and 3. r1==r2==42, is caused by compiler's aggressive value prediction and speculation. Although it's possible, is unacceptable.So JMM disallow behavior.My explain is right?

Comment: @Hanter Yes. JMM disallow it.

Comment: thx.I don't understand compiler's aggressive value prediction and speculation.I briefly put it to one side.I'm reading JSR133 and JMM.